# Installed tcllib (for globus-personal connect) but cannot find it

Tags: tcl, debian-stretch, globus-toolkit

I am on a Debain Stretch machine. I tried running ./globusconnectpersonal after downloading it from the globus website and it returned the phrase

```
my@cpu:~/script/globusconnectpersonal-2.3.6$ ./globusconnectpersonal
Tcllib not found.
The Globus Connect Personal GUI requires Tcllib.
Please install Tcllib using your distributions package management system.
On Debian based systems (e.g. Ubunutu):
  apt-get install tcllib
On Redhat based systems (e.g. CentOS, Fedora):
  yum install tcllib
 Note: if you encounter an error about tcllib not being
 available, it can be found here and installed manually:
 http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcllib/
You may also run Globus Connect Personal in CLI mode.
Please use the -help option or visit http://globus.org/globus-connect-personal/
for more information.
```

So I ran apt-get install tcllib but I recieve the same message. This is weird for two reasons. First this is some output I get to check whether or not I have it downloaded.

```
my@cpu:~$ dpkg -l | grep tcl
ii  libtcl8.6:amd64                               8.6.6+dfsg-1+b1                             amd64        Tcl (the Tool Command Language) v8.6 - run-time library files
ii  tcl                                           8.6.0+9                                     amd64        Tool Command Language (default version) - shell
ii  tcl-dev:amd64                                 8.6.0+9                                     amd64        Tool Command Language (default version) - development files
ii  tcl8.6                                        8.6.6+dfsg-1+b1                             amd64        Tcl (the Tool Command Language) v8.6 - shell
ii  tcl8.6-dev:amd64                              8.6.6+dfsg-1+b1                             amd64        Tcl (the Tool Command Language) v8.6 - development files
ii  tcllib                                        1.18-dfsg-3                                 all          Standard Tcl Library
ii  tcllib-critcl:amd64                           1.18-dfsg-3                                 amd64        Standard Tcl Library (CriTcl accelerators)

my@cpu:~$ whereis tcllib
tcllib:
```

So what exactly is happening? Do I need to change my paths or something so that my laptop can recognize it?

Comment: What is that program doing when it emits that "Tcllib not found" error? You'll have to dig into the code a little bit.

Comment: You will have to be more specific about how you obtained global connect, and how you try to run it. Seems this is specific to your setup: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115411/globus-personal-connect-tcllib-installed-but-keeps-showing-tcllib-not-found

Comment: What is the output of running: `echo 'puts $auto_path; package req csv' | tclsh` (this approximates what `globalconnect.tcl` is about to attempt.)?

Comment: @mrcalvin I have the same issue and when I run your line there the output is `/home/owner/anaconda3/lib/tcl8.6 /home/owner/anaconda3/lib
can't find package csv`